# Why the returning from a double function becomes int?

Tags: c, int, double

I have a double function like this:

```
double f(){
     double value=0.1234;
     return value;
}
```

In another function I received the value and printed it.

```
printf("%f",f());
```

I would like to see the value 0.1234 was printed, but instead 0 was printed.
If I cast the type like this:

```
printf("%f",(double)f());
```

a very strange value like -147923499.34 would be printed.

After some checking (print sizeof) I found that the returned value from f() was 4 bytes, while the double type should be 8 bytes.

So, what is the root reason of this? How can I return the correct double value from the function?

Comment: [Seems to work fine](http://ideone.com/IaZyOU). Please post a minimal compilable program that demonstrates your error.

Comment: Maybe you did not have the prototype in scope when you called `f()`

Comment: @Alfie: That is not how precedence works and if it was it wouldn't have compiled for at least two reasons.

Comment: Is it C or C++?  You have both tags but they are different languages.

Comment: **C is not C++**, and this question is exactly why there is a difference.  Your code will fail to compile in C++ without prototyping the function.  In C (C89) that code will compile just fine, but will have undesirable effects, **like behaving as the function returns an int when it actually returns a double**.  So don't tag questions as both C and C++.  Instead, choose the language you're actually using and apply that tag to your question.

Comment: Unless you have the exact same code in two files (something.c and something.cpp), and you're compiling and linking it twice (once with a C compiler and then again with a C++ compiler) and getting the same issue in both executables, this **cannot** be tagged both C and C++. What **specific** language are you using? Remove the tag that does not apply. Do not add tags just because they seem similar or start with the same letter - a cat and a car are not related because they both start with *ca*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you called `f()` without a prototype in scope. In C89, the compiler reacts to this by assuming `f` returns `int`.  If the implementation of `f` does not actually return `int` then the behaviour is undefined.

In C++, and in C since C99, there must be a warning at least for this code. Check your compiler output and I would recommend that you pay attention to any warning messages, and if there were none, turn up the warning level.

To fix the code, write a prototype:

```
double f(void);
```

before calling the function. It's normal to place the prototype in a header file which is included by both the code calling the function, and the code implementing the function. Then the compiler will detect a mismatch between call and implementation.

Comment: The problem was resolved after I declared the prototype in head file. And I have removed the C++ tag of the question.

Comment: @Akr Cool . I suggest making sure that you are getting compiler warnings for the unfixed version of the code, in case you have similar errors elsewhere in your program

Comment: Thank you. This is a very funny thing with C89.